# failed to open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, wayland, drm

I am trying to get Chromium to run with hardware acceleration on an embedded ARM board (under Wayland), however when I run it I get

```
libEGL warning: failed to open /dev/dri/card0: Permission denied
```

And it is true, I cannot access `/dev/dri/card0` as a user. I added myself to `video` and rebooted, but it didn't help. I *should* have permissions. Is there anything like ACL, SELinux, that could be blocking me?

```
$ sudo ls -hal /dev/dri
total 0
drwxrw-rw-   3 root root        120 Dec 16 11:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  16 root root       3.7K Dec 16 11:55 ..
drwxrw-rw-   2 root root        100 Dec 16 11:55 by-path
crwxrw-rw-+  1 root video  226,   0 Sep  7 18:34 card0
crwxrw-rw-+  1 root video  226,   1 Dec 16 11:55 card1
crwxrw-rw-+  1 root render 226, 128 Dec 16 11:55 renderD128
```

```
$ sudo getfacl /dev/dri/card0
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/dri/card0
# owner: root
# group: video
user::rwx
user:jdm:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::rw-
```